# Nodemailer problems with tls/certificate (SMTP)

Tags: node.js, email, ssl, nodemailer

I want to send an e-mail with nodemailer, my configurations are:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.mydomain.de',
    port: 25,
    logger: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'info@mydomain.de',
        password: 'mypassword',
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'info@mydomain.de',
    to: recipient,
    subject: 'subject',
    text: '<p>hallo</p>'
};


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error in sendMail:");
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

I got an error: "Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames:...", after some research i added:

```
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
```

to my transporter. And now i get:

Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

I have no idea, what to change. I have the certificate for sending with SSL, but don't know where to put it nor which credentials are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following tls options if you're ok with disabling TLS

```
tls: {
    secure: false,
    ignoreTLS: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

Comment: I changed it and get: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames

Comment: try keeping rejectUnauthorized: false as well, edited answer

Comment: and now again: Send Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Comment: Please check if the email service you're using requires Oauth